# C# - Use Windows 10 'Microsoft Print to PDF' for multiple images

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, windows-10

I want to print multiple images to a pdf file, but not using the regular print-dialogue, but the 'print pictures' dialogue (see image below). As a printer, I want to use the 'Microsoft print to PDF'-Printer, which comes with windows 10.

My current code looks like this:

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\mt\Pictures\test\test.jpg";
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
p.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
p.Start();
```

So far so good, the right dialogue is showing. I tried it first with other methods, which didn't give me this one. I can now print one image to a pdf page, but how do I add other images? Additionally, in this solution, I can't  see how to set the printing-settings, like size of the image, which should be as large as possible without cutting the image and changing to horizontal format.

Earlier, I had this code:

```
try
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = STR_PRINTER_NAME;
    pd.Print();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\mt\Pictures\test\1.jpg");
    Point loc = new Point(100, 100);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);
    img.Dispose();
}
```

which I changed for the 'Print Picture'-Dialog. In the end, the dialog itself doesn't matter, but the 'Print Picture'-Dialog got all settings I need. The only thing the user has to set, is the name for the pdf-file.
[image: Print Picture - Dialogue]

Answer (score 0):

Solved the 'Multiple-Page' problem with the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imgs.Add(img1);
    imgs.Add(img2);
    imgs.Add(img3);
    imgs.Add(img4);

    try
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);

        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
        pd.Print();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;

    Point p = new Point(10, 10);
    Image img = Image.FromFile(imgs.ElementAt(page));
    graphic.DrawImage(img, p);
    page++;
    e.HasMorePages = page < imgs.Count;
    img.Dispose();
}
```

Still couldn't figure out how to set maximum size

Comment: Hi! I'am trying to use your code but this code is NOT opening Print Picture Dialog. Is there any way to open it?